# Something is overriding some of my jigoshop widgets

Tags: php, jquery, jigoshop

I'm creating my first eCommerce wordpress website which I have work on for weeks now, I'm nearly at finished but some of the jigoshop widgets and features are not working for example the price filter is not showing up and the fancy box feature isn't showing up too.

I have a demo of the site up at http://demo.remi-niscenthair.com/shop/ I would be very grateful for any advice on how to get these issues sorted.

Answer (score 0):

I would check their knowledge base: http://forum.jigoshop.com/kb
A lot of items are listed but some say "Subscribe to our support" for the answer and you would pay money: http://jigoshop.com/support/

Their plugins are not as well documented as others and they do not respond that well in forums.

Email me if you need more info: matt@thebc.co